# Как создать зависимость между анимацией блока и прокруткой страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так чтобы воспроизведение анимации блока (блок в позиции fixed) зависело от скролла что-то на подобие canvas, только не отрисовкой миллионов изображений а именно анимацией как к примеру в css, потому что отрисовка миллиона изображений нагружает очень сильно сеть и не всегда успевает загружаться что приводит к многочисленным ошибкам.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1019076/188366

Comment: Там показан пример с увеличением и вращением а мне нужно чтобы объект перемещался по странице

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1032117/188366

Comment: на этом ресурсе есть поиск ;)

Comment: спасибо, но опять же тут показаны такие же вычисление как и в первом ответе, а требуется настройка положения и трансформаций элемента как с ключевыми кадрами

Comment: хорошо бы сразу в вопросе отражать все хотелки..